# Image is not showing up on my webpage

Tags: html, css

The image tag does not work. Not sure if I'm missing something or I added the image tag incorrectly. The image is in the same folder, so there's no problem in inserting the picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="type the content description here" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="type, keywords, here" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    h1.align1 { text-align: center; }
    h2.align2 { text-align: center; }
    h3.align3 { text-align: center; }
    </style> 
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;"> 
    <h1 class="align1" style="color: yellow;"><font size="8"> TEXT </h1>
    <hr style="white" />
    <h2 class="align2" style="color: red;"><font size="10"> TEXT </h2>
    <hr style="white" />
    <h3 class="align3" style="color: blue;"><font size="10"> TEXT </h3> 
    <img src="years1.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us your folder structure

Comment: HTML code isn't enough, we need a proof that image exists in the directory

Comment: you have a lot of Syntax issue, non closing tab, using style in wrong way, etc  you should revise some HTML basis

Comment: Use "inspect element" in your browser (non-IE) to debug the location, where your image should be. In inspector's "Network" tab you can see, if the image is possible to load for browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your font tags (the unfinished tags may affect elements following these, in this case "image").

For example:

```
<h1 class="align1" style="color: yellow;"><font size="8"> TEXT </font></h1>
```

font tag is <del>deprecated</del> obsolete in HTML5 anyway, so you should write like this:

```
<h1 class="align1" style="color: yellow; font-size: 8em; "> TEXT </h1>
```

Comment: Yes, the unfinished font tag blocks/breaks image in my Chrome.

Comment: In HTML5 "font" is obsolete and this creates an unspecified situation, as any other custom element when it is not closed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 0):

It's a img path issue. Please use a suitable file path for the image,
and also remove the font tag and use it under style.